# How to avoid an array of chars to be displayed in text plain on the binary file

Tags: c

So, I have been developing a code where some information should not be easily found if someone runs a `strings` command against the binary ie: `strings a.out`

If I try to use the following:

```
char array1[] = { 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd',  '\0' };
```

then it works perfectly fine and it wouldn't be displayed if I run the strings command against the binary file.

However, I have a bigger list of text, which is converted to hex and if I try to use this list in the code below, after I compile the code, if I run a strings command against the binary, the list will be easily displayed in plain text.

```
unsigned char array1[] = {
    0x64, 0x64, 0x64, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x0a, 0x62, 0x62,
    0x62, 0x62, 0x20, 0x63, 0x63, 0x63, 0x63, 0x64, 0x0a
};
```

My goal here is not to encrypt anything, but just try to avoid the content from being easily displayed if someone runs the strings command against the binary.

does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You already seem to have a solution to this problem ("works perfectly fine").

Comment: it works when I use a single text like --> aaaaaa
However if I try to use a list of strings like:
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
eee ffff
then it displays the full content in the binary

Comment: I believe the solution that "worked perfectly fine" worked only because it happened to use strings too short for the `strings` command to find by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My idea is using `float` to store the value to used in initialization and converting the values to `unsigned char` at run time.

```c
float array1_f[] = {
  0x64, 0x64, 0x64, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x0a, 0x62, 0x62,
  0x62, 0x62, 0x20, 0x63, 0x63, 0x63, 0x63, 0x64, 0x0a
};
unsigned char array1[sizeof(array1_f) / sizeof(*array1_f)];

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array1) / sizeof(*array1); i++) {
  array1[i] = (unsigned char)array1_f[i];
}
```

Floating-point values have a different representation compared to integers (for example, the value `0x64` (100) is represented as `0x42c80000` in IEEE-754 32-bit `float`), so it should be enough to hide your data from `strings`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a simplistic cipher in the source file and restore the string at runtime:

```
#define X(c)  (0x60 ^ (c))
char array1[] = {
    X('d'), X('d'), X('d'), X('d'), X(' '), X('a'), X('a'), X('a'),
    X('a'), X('\n'), X('b'), X('b'), X('b'), X('b'), X(' '), X('c'),
    X('c'), X('c'), X('c'), X('d'), X('\n')
};

void init_function(void) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array1); i++) {
        array1[i] = X(array1[i]);
    }
}
```

Even simpler if you don't mind the phrase appearing as clear text in the source file:

```
#include <stddef.h>

wchar_t array1_w[] = L"dddd aaaa\nbbbb ccccd\n";
char array1[sizeof(array1_w) / sizeof(*array1_w)];

void init_function(void) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array1); i++) {
        array1[i] = (char)array1_w[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yunnosch: a simple xor hardly qualifies as *encryption*

Comment: Hi Yunnosch, I have no problem on encrypting it... I just thought that encrypting would be a bit more harder to code so thats why I was not considering this option, but anything that could prevent the content to be displayed is still valid, either encryption or any other way.

Comment: @Yunnosch: In cryptography, a *cipher* (or *cypher*) is an algorithm for performing encryption or decryption, but it usually refers to simple algorithms used in historical applications (Caesar, Vigenere...) I am not a native speaker, so I could be wrong, but this term seems old fashioned and fits the purpose in my answer.

Comment: Too intricate a term discussion for this topic (me not being native either). I am satisfied that OP likes the answer. I also admit I was too nitpicky and overshot my goal to support OP in getting an answer. Actually I thought practically the same as a solution....